# Unexplained errors in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm making a small framework around OpenGL for creating a simple 2D game.
When i finished my Texture class and used it in my engine Thogl (Orthogonal OpenGL) class
i got a lot of unexplained errors that don't make sense.
I tried to find it but i just can't figure it out, i hoped you guys could hem me. I'm using the libraries: GLEW, GLFW, OpenGL32, GLM.

My code

Texture.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Magick++.h>
#include "Thogl.h"

class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(GLenum textureTarget);
    ~Texture();

    bool LoadImage(const char* fileName);

    void Bind(GLenum textureUnit);

    Magick::Image* image;

private:
    Magick::Blob blob;

    GLuint textureObject;
    GLenum textureTarget;
};
```

Texture.cpp

```
#include "Texture.h"

Texture::Texture(GLenum target)
{
    textureTarget = target;
    image = NULL;
}
Texture::~Texture()
{
}

bool Texture::LoadImage(const char* fileName)
{
    try
    {
        image = new Magick::Image(fileName);
        image->write(&blob, "RGBA");
    }
    catch(Magick::Error error)
    {
        Error (error.what());
        return false;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &textureObject);
    glBindTexture(textureTarget, textureObject);
    glTexImage2D(textureTarget, 0, GL_RGBA, image->columns(), image->rows(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blob.data());
    glTexParameterf(textureObject, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(textureObject, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return true;
}

void Texture::Bind(GLenum textureUnit)
{
    glActiveTexture(textureUnit);
    glBindTexture(textureTarget, textureObject);
}
```

Thogl.h

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <map>
#include "Texture.h"


using namespace std;

class Thogl
{
public:
    Thogl();
    ~Thogl();

    bool init(int windowWidth, int windowHeight, const char* windowTitle);

    Texture* CreateTexture(const char* textureName, const char* fileName);
    Texture* CreateTexture(const char* textureName);

    void Start(void (*RunCallback)());

private:
    void run();
    GLFWwindow* window;
    static void KeyCallback(GLFWwindow*, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
    void SetCallbacks();
    void Terminate();
    map<string, Texture*> Textures;
    void (*RunCallback)(); 
};


void Error(const char* error);
```

Thogl.cpp

```
#include "Thogl.h"

ofstream errorLog;


Thogl::Thogl()
{
    Magick::Image* image;
    Magick::Blob blob;
    try
    {
        image = new Magick::Image("//Lol.png");
        image->write(&blob);
    }
    catch(Magick::Error error)
    {
        Error(error.what());
    }
}
Thogl::~Thogl()
{
}

void Thogl::run()
{
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        RunCallback();


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

bool Thogl::init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, const char* windowTitle)
{
    errorLog.open("Error.log");

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        Error("Could not initialize GLFW library");
        return false;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, windowTitle, NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        errorLog << "Error: Could not initialize GLFW window\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        errorLog << "Error GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString(error) << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    SetCallbacks();

    glClearColor(138.f,43.f,226.f, 0);

    return true;
}

void Thogl::KeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{

}

void Thogl::SetCallbacks()
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, KeyCallback);
}

void Thogl::Terminate()
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    errorLog.close();
}

void Error(const char* error)
{
    errorLog << "Error: " << error << "\n";
}

void Thogl::Start(void (*Callback)())
{
    RunCallback = Callback;
    run();
}

Texture* Thogl::CreateTexture(const char* textureName, const char* fileName)
{
    Texture* newTexture = new Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    if (!newTexture->LoadImage(fileName))
    {
        Error("Couldn't load image file");
        return 0;
    }

    Textures.insert(make_pair(textureName, newTexture));

    return newTexture;
}

Texture* Thogl::CreateTexture(const char* textureName)
{
    Texture *newTexture = new Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    Textures.insert(make_pair(textureName, newTexture));

    return newTexture;
}
```

Here is the output when compiling on VS2010 express:

```
>------ Build started: Project: 2DEngine, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>  Thogl.cpp
>  Texture.cpp
> thogl.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
> thogl.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> thogl.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> thogl.h(25): warning C4183: 'CreateTexture': missing return type; assumed to be a member function     returning 'int'
> thogl.h(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
> thogl.h(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> thogl.h(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> thogl.h(26): warning C4183: 'CreateTexture': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
> thogl.h(36): error C2065: 'Texture' : undeclared identifier
> thogl.h(36): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
> thogl.h(38): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
> texture.h(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
> texture.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
> texture.cpp(4): error C2653: 'Texture' : is not a class or namespace name
> texture.cpp(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
> texture.cpp(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
> texture.cpp(9): error C2653: 'Texture' : is not a class or namespace name
> texture.cpp(9): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
>  Generating Code...
>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
>  Main.cpp
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This code sample is far too big to qualify as a minimal test case that illustrates the problem. But, fwiw, many of the errors suggest that at least part of your problem is a failure to put a semicolon after class or strict declarations.

Comment: I thought the more code the better to find the problem, and you ca  easily navigate by looking at the error lines to see where it points at

Comment: Edit Texture.h, add the missing semi-colon.

Comment: To put it simply, you're asking people to take time to help you. It's polite to show that you realize this by narrowing down your question to something specific. You're much more likely to get a relevant answer with "why don't these ten lines compile?" than with "please find the bug(s) in the following 300 lines of code."

Comment: yes i know, but i thought that it could have been a way more complicated thing that caused the error, so i didn't know what you would need to find it. I'm sorry if there was to much code, i was only trying to be as complete as possible. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I can understand that without knowing the problem it's nearly impossible to know when you've posted enough code. And, generally, we ask people to err on the side of posting a little too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between the two header files. They include each other. But the compiler skips the circular includes (you told it to do so with `#pragma once`) and in the file that gets parsed first the types from the other file will be unknown, leading to errors.

To fix this, you should remove he circular include (`Texture.h` doesn't seem to require `Thogl.h`) or use forward declarations of required types.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, i haven't ever got this kind of error, thanks for not just being a downvoter and actually answering, even though theres a lot of code. I'm very grateful!